# Problems obtaining tracking into Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

We are trying to get information about triggered email´s tracking with survey.

We have sent several triggered email´s with the same survey today. In the aplication, we can see the tracking of all.
We have got the tracking from `_SurveyResponse` with a query into a Data Extension, but only have recieved the first registers.

We need to get the last registers, but ORDER BY is no the way, because `_SurveyResponse` it´s a view.

¿Do you know how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _surveyresponse view, have only one data entry for each survey.
The _Sent view, content the entries for each email

Comment: Sorry - I flagged this as not an answer, I may have been mistaken. You are saying to get the info, you should use the _Sent view, and you have it working as you wanted now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have found the tracking info in surveyresponse view and emails info in sent view correctly.

Thankyou